# I need to have my function repeat it self for each item in array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, arrays

I am trying to make a button for each item in my array (from the db). Right now the first button will work the way it is suppose to but all the ones under it will do nothing. I've tried many different thing but can't seem to get it to work. If you need more code or have any question just let me know.

```
<html>

<head>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="photos/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js "></script>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
</head><div id="container" >



<head>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="photos/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js "></script>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
</head>          
<div id='header'>
<header >
<hr size="50px" color="#ff0000" text-align="right" value="Dustin's Resume" >
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/script.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/style.css' />
 <div class='menu'>
<img  class="hover-link" id="logo3" src="photos/logo3.png"   height="50px" align="left" alt="logo"  >
 <!--<a class='hover-link'>Navigation</a>-->
 <div class='sub'>
 <ul class='sub-options'>
  <li><a href="profile2.php?id=1"><img src="upload/142479139.jpg" width="100px" height="100px" text-align="center"/></a><br></li>
 <li><a href='default.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>Home</b></h3></a></li>
 <li><a href='about.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>About</b></h3></a></li>
 <li><a href='members.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>Search</b></h3></a></li>
 <li><a href='contact.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>Contact</b></h3></a></li>
  <li><a href='update.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>Update Info</b></h3></a></li>
   <li><a href='updatepic.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>Update Pic</b></h3></a></li>
   <li><a href='logout.php' style="text-size:30px;font-weight:bold;"><b>Logout</b></h3></a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
<style>
#welcome {
margin-top: 0px;
color: #fff;
font: bold, 25px;
align: right;
}
</style>


<image align="right" position='fixed' id="logo" src="upload/142479139.jpg" width="50px" height="50px"></image>

    <p id='welcome' align='right'>Welcome back,<br></p>     

</header>

<head>


<link rel="shortcut icon" href="photos/favicon.ico" >
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/home.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js "></script>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>
</head><aside >
    <div >

    <br>
             <p align="center"> 
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/scripts.js"></script>
</head>


            <form>
                <div class="label_div">Search People</div><br>
                <div class="input_container">
                    <input type="text" id="id" onkeyup="autocomplet()" autocomplete="off">
                    <ul id="list_id"></ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        </p>
             <a href="updatepic.php" alt="Update Picture"><image align="center" src="upload/142479139.jpg" width="150px" height="150px"></image></a>
             <br><br><br>
             <p><h3>Dustin Strader</h3></p>

    </div>

</aside><body><div id="content" ><script type="text/javascript">
function setbg(color)
{
document.getElementById("styled").style.background=color
}</script>




</head>

  <table align="center" >
    <tr>
      <td padding="10px" width="600" height="200" style="background-image: url('photos/post.png');  ">
      <a href="profile2.php?id=1" ><image  align="right" style="margin:0 50 0"  src="upload/142479139.jpg" width="75px" height="75px"></a>
    <div align="center"><label style="margin:0 0" id="px" >Damn I got this shit down!!!</label><br>












            <label style="margin:0 0; font-size:8px" id="px" >2014-06-19 03:28:36am</label><br></div>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="POST" action="default.php" >
    <label style="margin:0 0">
    <textarea maxlength="40" name="comment" id="" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#ffffff');" onblur="setbg('white')">Comment...</textarea>
    </label><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="101" ></input>
        <div style=" margin:0 152px 0"  align="center"> <input  type="image" width="100px" height="35px" name="submits" src="photos/comment.png" alt="submit" />
<a href="vcomments.php?id=101" align="center"></a>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
effect: "blind",
duration: 1000},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 1000
}}); 
$( ".opener" ).live('click',function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
}); 
}); 




  </script>
</head>
<image class="opener" width="100px" height="35px"  src="photos/vcomment.png" > 






<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>
  <label   ><p>2014-06-19 03:28:36</p></label><br>
<label   ><h3>Damn I got this shit down!!!</h3></label><br>
  <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 23:59:39</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">777777777777777</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 23:53:36</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">1111111111</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-21 00:33:10</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">9999999999999</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-21 00:32:32</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">44444444444444444</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 17:23:11</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">cccccc</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 16:50:51</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">hgjghjghj</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 16:24:43</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">ffffffff</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 14:24:05</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">jhnfgn</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 14:24:00</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">fgdfg</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-19 04:34:09</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">Comment...</p></label><br>
  </p>



 </div>
</div>  </form> </div >     
  </td>



    </tr>
  <table>




</head>

  <table align="center" >
    <tr>
      <td padding="10px" width="600" height="200" style="background-image: url('photos/post.png');  ">
      <a href="profile2.php?id=1" ><image  align="right" style="margin:0 50 0"  src="upload/142479139.jpg" width="75px" height="75px"></a>
    <div align="center"><label style="margin:0 0" id="px" >I love this site!!!</label><br>












            <label style="margin:0 0; font-size:8px" id="px" >2014-06-19 02:00:36am</label><br></div>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="POST" action="default.php" >
    <label style="margin:0 0">
    <textarea maxlength="40" name="comment" id="" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#ffffff');" onblur="setbg('white')">Comment...</textarea>
    </label><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="100" ></input>
        <div style=" margin:0 152px 0"  align="center"> <input  type="image" width="100px" height="35px" name="submits" src="photos/comment.png" alt="submit" />
<a href="vcomments.php?id=100" align="center"></a>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
effect: "blind",
duration: 1000},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 1000
}}); 
$( ".opener" ).live('click',function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
}); 
}); 




  </script>
</head>
<image class="opener" width="100px" height="35px"  src="photos/vcomment.png" > 






<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>
  <label   ><p>2014-06-19 02:00:36</p></label><br>
<label   ><h3>I love this site!!!</h3></label><br>
  <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 23:58:13</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">Comment...</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 13:44:55</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">Comment...</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 13:42:38</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">Comment...</p></label><br>
  </p>



   <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-19 05:12:37</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">i kove tis</p></label><br>
  </p>



 </div>
</div>  </form> </div >     
  </td>



    </tr>
  <table>




</head>

  <table align="center" >
    <tr>
      <td padding="10px" width="600" height="200" style="background-image: url('photos/post.png');  ">
      <a href="profile2.php?id=25" ><image  align="right" style="margin:0 50 0"  src="upload/425876911.jpg" width="75px" height="75px"></a>
    <div align="center"><label style="margin:0 0" id="px" >Today is a cool day.</label><br>












            <label style="margin:0 0; font-size:8px" id="px" >2014-06-18 03:38:45pm</label><br></div>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="POST" action="default.php" >
    <label style="margin:0 0">
    <textarea maxlength="40" name="comment" id="" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#ffffff');" onblur="setbg('white')">Comment...</textarea>
    </label><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="92" ></input>
        <div style=" margin:0 152px 0"  align="center"> <input  type="image" width="100px" height="35px" name="submits" src="photos/comment.png" alt="submit" />
<a href="vcomments.php?id=92" align="center"></a>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
effect: "blind",
duration: 1000},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 1000
}}); 
$( ".opener" ).live('click',function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
}); 
}); 




  </script>
</head>
<image class="opener" width="100px" height="35px"  src="photos/vcomment.png" > 






<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>
  <label   ><p>2014-06-18 15:38:45</p></label><br>
<label   ><h3>Today is a cool day.</h3></label><br>
  <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 13:40:09</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">55555</p></label><br>
  </p>



 </div>
</div>  </form> </div >     
  </td>



    </tr>
  <table>




</head>

  <table align="center" >
    <tr>
      <td padding="10px" width="600" height="200" style="background-image: url('photos/post.png');  ">
      <a href="profile2.php?id=25" ><image  align="right" style="margin:0 50 0"  src="upload/425876911.jpg" width="75px" height="75px"></a>
    <div align="center"><label style="margin:0 0" id="px" >Dustin Rocks</label><br>












            <label style="margin:0 0; font-size:8px" id="px" >2014-06-18 03:38:34pm</label><br></div>
    <div align="center">
    <form method="POST" action="default.php" >
    <label style="margin:0 0">
    <textarea maxlength="40" name="comment" id="" onfocus="this.value=''; setbg('#ffffff');" onblur="setbg('white')">Comment...</textarea>
    </label><br><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="ids" value="91" ></input>
        <div style=" margin:0 152px 0"  align="center"> <input  type="image" width="100px" height="35px" name="submits" src="photos/comment.png" alt="submit" />
<a href="vcomments.php?id=91" align="center"></a>



  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
show: {
effect: "blind",
duration: 1000},
hide: {
effect: "explode",
duration: 1000
}}); 
$( ".opener" ).live('click',function() {
$( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" ); 
}); 
}); 




  </script>
</head>
<image class="opener" width="100px" height="35px"  src="photos/vcomment.png" > 






<div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
  <p>
  <label   ><p>2014-06-18 15:38:34</p></label><br>
<label   ><h3>Rocks</h3></label><br>
  <label   ><p align="center">2014-06-20 13:40:16</p></label><br>
<label  ><p align="center">5555</p></label><br>
  </p>



 </div>
</div>  </form> </div >     
  </td>



    </tr>
  <table>




</div>

</body>

</div>


</html>
```

Comment: please, provide rendered html and specify, where are your buttons (id, class etc)

Comment: If you are using id="opener" for the buttons, try class instead since ids should be unique.

Comment: `$('#dialog').each`, element `ID` must be unique. Use a class instead.

Comment: Added html, please help!!

Comment: I think I have never seen such a broken HTML page layout... You have 10 `<head>` elements & reinclude all your resources at least twice...????

Answer (score 0):

As you say, it seems elements don't have unique id. Either use unique id for each element and declare related click event which might be long way, or add class instead of id and add click event with **'live/ on'** binding, i.e

```
$(".buttonClasss").live('click',function(){
    //rest of you code.
 });
```

Comment: when I do this it shows all the results but not in the dialog box. it just prints everything out on the page.

Comment: First I can't understand y u r making dialog loop when u have jst 1 element on page. Please Update your script with following one and add this just before closing of body tag. 
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( "#dialog" ).dialog({autoOpen: false,show: {effect: "blind",duration: 1000},hide: {effect: "explode",duration: 1000}});

            $( ".opener" ). live('click',function() {
                $( "#dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
              });
  });
    </script>

Comment: that hide everything but still no button click on any of the buttons

Comment: can u please post view source of your page?